# Not able to install hbase-stargate gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems, hbase, stargate

I am trying to install hbase-stargate gem on my hadoop machine having centos-5.8 OS. Hbase is already installed. I am getting below errors.

gem install hbase-stargate
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing hbase-stargate:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for curl-config... no
checking for main() in -lcurl... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/bin/ruby
    --with-curl-dir
    --without-curl-dir
    --with-curl-include
    --without-curl-include=${curl-dir}/include
    --with-curl-lib
    --without-curl-lib=${curl-dir}/lib
    --with-curllib
    --without-curllib
extconf.rb:34:   Can't find libcurl or curl/curl.h (RuntimeError)

Try passing --with-curl-dir or --with-curl-lib and --with-curl-include
  options to extconf.

Gem files will remain installed in /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/patron-0.4.18 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/patron-0.4.18/ext/patron/gem_make.out

Its giving errors about libcurl however libcurl and libcurl-devel package is also there...

Answer (score 3):

I also got this error while installing 'patron' gem on Ubuntu 12.04 with Rails 3.2.12.

I fixed this issue using:

```
sudo apt-get install libcurl3-dev
```

and then:

```
bundle
```

I hope it will be helpfull

Comment: its a centos machine so apt-get wont work but yeah libcurl-dev solved the issue.